# Which is the easiest way for putting citations and references?

Tags: citation-style, reference-managers, cross-referencing

Most easy way to put references & citations?

Comment: Maybe edit your question to give a broader description of what your problem is to get better answers.

Comment: Zotero is a free, open-source management tool for references and bibliographies.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

[Reference management software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software).